# Mailchimp Subscriber Popup widget does not show the email maling list popup

Tags: email, popup, subscription

I have created a Mailchimp account and do everything that is necessary to get the code for a mailchimp subscriber popup code. Especially, I followed every step at https://jetpack.com/support/extra-sidebar-widgets/mailchimp-subscriber-popup-widget/

I added the Mailchimp Subscriber Popup widget to the Sidebar of my Wordpress page as widget and pasted the code I received from Mailchimp for the popup which looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us19.list-manage.com","uuid":"cb350efb387f17cea07bb0b20","lid":"e0a6f2c5c5","uniqueMethods":true}) })</script>
```

But when I click on "Done" and "Publish" button for the widget, wordpress does not show the popup. Additionally, the script from above is changed to the following:

```
<a href="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js">//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js</a>window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us19.list-manage.com","uuid":"cb350efb387f17cea07bb0b20","lid":"e0a6f2c5c5","uniqueMethods":true}) })
```

I have read that it has to do with the script tag and that is not allowed.
All solutions that I have found involve the need for a plugin. But I use my wordpress blog for free so that I can not install plugins. 
So, is there any other solutions in my case ?